# How to remove memtest86 menu entries from Grub 2

Tags: grub2, 15.04, memtest

How to hide/remove memtest86 menu entries from Grub2. I have Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I want only items that will be used

Comment: @Pilot6 what for? Can't it be accessed via advanced options? what does it do?

Comment: This is not about boot order.

Comment: @Pilot6 no it isn't. same answer though. more helpful than leaving open.

Comment: @Tim So it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Tim maybe duplicate, unfortunately i can be sure (can't test it), because 20_memtest86+ file is gone, after i used grub-customizer to change entry name.

Comment: @Pilot6 nope it isn't. feel free not to close it. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14359/should-questions-be-closed-as-duplicate-only-because-of-the-helpfulness-of-answe?cb=1 my opinion is may as well close it.

Comment: @Tim and it's  not a good way to install unknown third party combo apps to solve one small problem

Comment: @JanKomadowski it's not great to remove a program tbh. anyway

Comment: @Tim When I don't use it I don't need it ;)

Comment: @JanKomadowski I don't use my house insurance. still have it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found. Maybe there is a better way but it works for me

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
```

and than

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It is not a bad idea.

Comment: But this can be reverted on a grub update.

Comment: Then I repeat the process. Worse if this option does not work after the update :/

Comment: I wrote an answer how to remove memtest.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `memtest86+` by running

```
sudo apt-get remove memtest86+
```

It can always be installed back by

```
sudo apt-get install memtest86+
```

Comment: Who downvoted and why?

Comment: Me, it's very short, doesn't explain how to revert the change or what "running" is (never a bad thing to explain). It also appeared in LQP queue because of length and content (another reason to downvote), as did another answer (not a reason). I allowed both to stay but wasn't sure. I've hence flagged this for custom moderator for them to decide what should happen.

Comment: @Tim It gives full explanation on what the command does. Short is not always bad. I added how to revert it.

Comment: If (when) you need to run `memtest86+`, your system will NOT be healthy enough to `sudo apt-get install memtest86+` - `memtest86+` is a tool to boot when Ubuntu cannot, and your computer has memory, and might have memory problems. Also, if `memtest86+` fails, your hardware problem is obvious.

Comment: @waltinator I wrote that in my comments too. But if someone wants to remove it, it is his/her choice. I never seriously used memtest in my life. I am probably lucky.

Comment: The denser memory gets (and I've seen "core memory" being made by hand), the more likely the Cosmic Ray God is to Zap! something. "We'll never need this diagnostic!" is never the beginning of a fun story.